# Bind datasource to persistence on Intellij fails on resolve column

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm starting learing how to use IntelliJ, and I'm trying to link my persistence to my datasource. 
I've read here on SO how to do that, and now I've binded my persistence to my datasource successfully: I can run queries on database, and i can browse my persistence.

This is the db (MSSQL):

[image]

This is the persistence:

[image]

And this is the assignment:

[image]

The problem is that I'm still getting error on my class, looks like is not able to link to the datasource, and is giving me the error "Cannot resolve column" (not only on ID column, but on all columns):

[image]

**The application is running fine, so the problem is only related to some wrong intellij configuration**, but I can't find where the problem is.

This is my hibernate.cfg.xml (there are more tables, I've left only the one in the example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="Artemide">
  <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>

  <!-- Configurazione maven-->
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">${hibernate.password}</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">${hibernate.username}</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">${hibernate.connection.url}</property>
  <property name="hibernate.default_catalog">${hibernate.default_catalog}</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
  <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>

  <mapping class="xx.xx.xx.database.pojo.Categoria"/>

 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you face this error for all columns? Is it possible to share your hibernate config file?

Comment: The problem is on all columns. I've added the hibernate config into the question (there are more tables than that, but I've removed the others for readability). Thanks!